# What's the most efficient way to find the smallest factor k of a given positive number n such that k^2>n?

Tags: algorithm, integer

I tried to search all integers from sqrt(n) but it really performs bad for some inputs that have fewer factors such as 15838 (2×7919, will loop for more than 7800 times). And I wonder if there a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I doubt it. You could work this out using the complete factorization of n, but we can't factor quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest factor k of n that's larger than sqrt(n) is n/k' where k' is the largest factor of n that's smaller than sqrt(n). So simply by searching downwards from ceil(sqrt(n))-1 and returning n/k when you find a factor k is an obvious O(sqrt(n)) algorithm compared to your current O(n) algorithm.

Comment: This can be improved if the answer is near `sqrt(n)` by using the fact that `(i+j)(i-j) = i*i - j*j`. But not by enough to be worthwhile. And you have to be careful about the fact that `i` and `j` might be half-integers. For example `(2.5+0.5)*(2.5-0.5) = 6`.